# How to properly paste new contents in Nautilus when in detail view?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

When Nautilus is in detail view and there are many sub folders and files in a directory, how does one paste new folders / files in the same parent directory?

See image:
[image]

So scrolling to the bottom of the list on the right, have no 'empty' area to right click in to say paste. So how do you paste into parent folder and not child sub folders?

Comment: Instead of copy/paste you could use 'copy to ...' in the source folder to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue in the nautilus version that comes with Ubuntu 18.10 and earlier (3.28 and earlier) that, in list view, there may be no "empty" space, allowing to trigger the right-click menu associated with no selection, i.e., the right-click menu you get right-clicking on a blanc space.

There will be improvements in the forthcoming Ubuntu, which will use nautilus 3.32, The "breadcrumb" navigation bar has been reworked in that version, making it more powerful. You will be able to obtain the context menu for the folder right-clicking the folder in the navigation bar.

In the mean time, you will need to do it another way.

- Solely with the mouse, there is not much more possible than a multi-step process. Click the parent folder on the navigation bar. This shows the parent folder with your working folder highlighted, which you can right-click for "Paste into folder".
- Work with two windows or tabs, one opened in source and another in destination, and drag files from source to destination.
- Use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste. In general, you can reveal the "empty spot" right-click menu, offering the "Paste" option, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Will the Gnome 3.32 functionality be back ported to 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Certainly not. Version up to Ubuntu 18.10 is 3.26 (even if Gnome shell is already 3.30 on 18.10). that was the last nautilus version that supported desktop icons.

Comment: Doesn't look like this will be solved anymore at all: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/41

Comment: @Sebastian This has been solved. In newer versions of nautilus, space to the left of the list provides the right-click menu for the folder.

Comment: cool, didn't know that. Still running 22.04